# My ApplicationBar is not displayed

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml, application-bar

I created an application for Windows Phone 8 with "Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone". I have a first page to log in and after the user go to a pivot with 4 pivotItems where I want to add a ApplicationBar. I created my applicationBar and it is well displayed on my design. When I launch my app on the emulator or my phone the bar doesn't appear.

Do you have any ideas to solve my problems?

i have already made all the msdn tutorials concerning the applicationBar.

Thanks a lot!

This is my xaml code:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="DemoWP.Home"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"    
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,5,0,0">
        <phone:Pivot Margin="0,0,0,0" Foreground="#3399cc">
            <phone:PivotItem CacheMode="{x:Null}" Header="Accueil">
                <Grid/>
            </phone:PivotItem>
            <phone:PivotItem CacheMode="{x:Null}" Header="Planning" >
                <Grid/>
            </phone:PivotItem>
            <phone:PivotItem CacheMode="{x:Null}" Header="Site">
                <Grid/>
            </phone:PivotItem>
            <phone:PivotItem CacheMode="{x:Null}" Header="Contact">
                <Grid/>
            </phone:PivotItem>
        </phone:Pivot>
    </Grid>

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True" Opacity ="1.0" BackgroundColor="#3399cc" Mode="Default">
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/feature.settings.png" Click="Settings_Click" Text="Paramètres"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/refresh.png" Click="Save_Click" Text="Actualiser"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Click="MenuItem1_Click" Text="Déconnexion"/>
            </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

And my c# code (very simple)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;



namespace DemoWP
{
    public partial class Home : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public Home()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }



        private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Save button works!");
            //Do work for your application here.
        }

        private void Settings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Settings button works!");
            //Do work for your application here.
        }

        private void MenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Menu item 1 works!");
            //Do work for your application here.
        }

        private void MenuItem2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Menu item 2 works!");
            //Do work for your application here.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I beleive it must be something in your c# code that is making the ApplicationBar disappear.
Can you show your c# code?

Comment: I don't do anything special in my c# as you can see. I really don't understand what happens

Comment: I just ran your code and I couldn't find anything wrong. And the application bar showed up correctly.

Comment: You ran it on a phone?  
Thank you very much!

Comment: I had run in an emulator, but now I ran in a phone as well and it worked fine as well.

Comment: It should come from my control properties but i don't know which one

Answer (score 0):

If it still isn't appearing in your emulator it may be some kind of bug within VS 2012. My suggestion would be to rebuild your project and then try and run it on the emulator again. That way you can be sure that your emulator is running your latest XAP.